# Bypassing a $watch function in AngularJS version 1.x

Tags: angularjs

I have a complex situation that I'm hoping to get some help with. We are developing a large-scale application using AngularJS 1.x for the front-end. I have a requirement to implement $dirty checking for forms when the user tries to exit the screen (on any page of the application). I wrote the following function in a directive that works well.

```
        function unsavedChanges($window, $uibModal) {
        var directiveObject = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linkerFn
        };

        return directiveObject;

        function linkerFn(scope, element, attrs) {
            var formName = attrs.name;

            $window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
                if (scope[formName].$dirty) {
                    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page? You may have unsaved changes.';
                }
            };

            scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event) {
                if (scope[formName].$dirty && !scope[formName].$submitted) {
                    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page? You may have unsaved changes.')) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now there is a requirement to also implement dirty checking for any array changes that occur as a result of changes in the UI. For example, there is a directive that allows the user to add multiple items selected from a modal. On confirm (in the modal), these items are added and rendered as a list in the UI. Each item can then be "marked for deletion". Actual deletion occurs on form submission (Save). The form should be dirty if any defined arrays are changed in any way (length, properties, etc.)

My solution was to use the already defined $watch function for each array, and set the form to $dirty = true, if any array changed. This also works as intended.

The problem is, when the user saves and submits the form, the resulting response contains the updated JSON data model (with any deleted array entries now removed). The updated data model is then re-assigned to the AngularJS data object which updates the UI. The UI updates cause the $watch functions to be triggered rendering the form dirty again. This is problematic since the user just saved and the form should be pristine. The ajax call sample is below:

```
Obj.save(dataObj).then(function(res) {
          var status = res.server_response.status;

          if (status >= 200 && status <= 210) {
       // The line below triggers the defined $watch functions
              vm.generalTrialDetailsObj = res;
              ...


              ...
          //Make sure $watch functions have completed before this is called.
              $scope.general_trial_form.$setPristine();  
          }
      })
```

I tried setting the form to pristine in the form submission save function, as part of the ajax success callback. However it seems that the $watch functions don't necessarily occur before I'm setting the form to pristine. Some can occur before and some after. So setting the form to pristine doesn't resolve the issue.

The only solution I could come up with was to refresh the page (we use angular ui-router) after save. This works but is unacceptable to the client, as a solution :)

Is there a way to make sure all $watch functions always complete before before I set the form to pristine? I can't come up with another solution just yet.

Thanks to anyone who can provide some guidance.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. Could you please help to modify this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/uax9y6f1/) to create the issue?

Comment: why aren't you extending ngModel? it seems to me that you try to recreate stuff that already is built in.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. , I'm not sure I follow. Extend ngModel to do what? (sorry I don't mean for this to sound rude). It seems as though what needs to happen is that the $watch functions need to be complete before i do form.$setPristine(). I played out yesterday using a timeout and it looks like if I run the pristine function after 1 second, that always works (ie: the watches are done, and the form is pristine after save) which is what I want. Do you see anything unsafe about this approach?

Comment: I guess my concern is whether there still a chance that the $watch function(s) run after pristine, for whatever reason.